# Git merge while discarding any previous changes(In local repository or from the last commit)

Tags: git, merge

In Git, during a merge, is there a way that we can tell git to discard local changes in case of a conflict and apply the changes from the merged branch?

I mean if there is a way, then we can do merges like branch merges without conflicts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to read about the merge strategies 'theirs' and 'ours'. When merging you can specify that either your current branch (ours) or the remote branch (theirs) is the correct one.

Comment: There is no strategy called `theirs`. Only options to the default `recursive` strategy called `theirs` and `ours`. There is a strategy called `ours`, howerer that is completely different from the two previously mentioned options.

Answer (score 3):

Before trying to merge, you can discard the local changes yourself `git reset --hard HEAD`.
You can replace `HEAD` by whatever commit hash you want.
This will bring you the the clean state of the commit you're actually *on*, and you'd lose all your changes.

If you want to keep them, you can stash them before with `git stash`, or move them to another branch:

```
git checkout -b new_branch
git add .
git commit -m "My awesome commit"
git checkout - # will bring you back to the last branch you were in
```

Comment: What I want is something like giving the priority to the remote content. In that way even Git finds conflicts, it'll go with the remote changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore all local changes, and an additional merge commit you want to just move your branch to the remote HEAD.

```
git log --oneline origin/master
# assume the first sha is bbdfa17
git reset --hard bbdfa17
```

Now you are at the tip of the tree with no merge commits.