# Git merge with overwriting local changes

Tags: git-merge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Git merge while discarding any previous changes(In local repository or from the last commit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737759/git-merge-while-discarding-any-previous-changesin-local-repository-or-from-the)

In a git merge, is there any way to tell to overwrite the local repository content and replace it with the remote content.

I mean in this way, we can avoid conflicts at known situations .

Comment: You just asked a question, you don't have to ask twice!

Comment: Sorry for any inconvenience. This was due to a network failure. I thought the previous one didn't get posted. That's why I put the new one.